# Optimization problems and quantifiers

Tags: optimization, logic

A simple optimization problem is of form $\max_{x\in\mathcal R}f(x)$.

We can quantify as $\exists x\in\mathcal R\forall y\in\mathcal R f(y)\leq f(x)$.

The quantification here is $\exists\forall$.

1. Is there a meaning to $\forall\exists$ from optimization?
2. What is a good natural meaning to $\forall\exists$ quantification?

Comment: $\forall x\in\mathcal R.\exists y\in\mathcal R.f(y)\leq f(x)$ is simply true tautologically.

Comment: I am looking for reasonable analogous interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The $\exists x \forall y$ form of quantification is used to indicate that there is some single object that has a particular relationship to all others, for instance an input that achieves the globally largest objective value in your example.

In $\forall y \exists x$ quantification, there can be a different $x$ for each $y$, but as pointed out in a comment, this is only interesting if the formula being quantified contains more than just a single inequality that allows setting $x=y$.  The existence of locally optimal values (that fail to achieve a globally maximal objective value, but are perhaps only a short distance away and still achieve an absolute target value for the objective function) would be expressed in this way.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Is it fair to tell optimization problems are in $\Sigma_2$?